# EXCEL - Comparing Two Columns - Removing Repeats

Tags: excel, compare, excel-2010

If two households share, they create a tie and this tie has a kinship rank that does not change, no matter how often two households share with each other.

**KINSHIP RANK EXAMPLE**

As you can see, it doesn't matter in which "direction" the tie happened whether it was household 5 who shared to household 3 or vice versa, the kinship rank is still 1

```
                           HH1   HH2   RANK
                            5     3      1
                            3     5      1
```

Therefore, I do not need every tie that occurs between two households, but only the ***first instance*** that a tie occurred between the two households.

So here is a sample list of many households who shared with each other, sometimes sharing resources with themselves, sharing only once, or sharing multiple times with the same household.

**TWO HOUSEHOLD WITH REPEATED TIES**

```
       COL.A  COL.B
ROW      HH1   HH2
 1        1     1
 2        1     2
 3        1     3
 4        2     1
 5        2     4
 6        3     1
 7        3     2
 8        3     4 
 9        4     2
```

This is what I need it to look like:

**TWO HOUSEHOLDS WITHOUT REPEATED TIES**

```
       COL.A  COL.B
ROW      HH1   HH2
 1        1     1
 2        1     2
 3        1     3
 4        2     4
 5        3     2
 6        3     4
```

**What I have done**

I wrote a simple command for placing the HH1 and HH2 information into the same cell:

=A1&"|"&B1

In the case of the second row, this looks like 1|2 inside cell C2

HH1 and HH2 are combined in column C so how will I be able to compare all of the households in column C to each other? Perhaps a highlighting rule if a repeat happens? Or in another column list if it is a delete or a keep?

Thank you for your assistance everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a simple COUNTIFS to do the job like this:

```
=(COUNTIFS(A$1:A1,B2,B$1:B1,A2)+COUNTIFS(A$1:A1,A2,B$1:B1,B2))>0
```

starting in C2 and then copy down. It will show TRUE for each row which is within the range above it and false if not. Ich checks for both x/y and y/x (the order doesn't matter)

Now simply filter col C to only show rows with TRUE in it. Then simply select and delete it.

This also works with non numerical values like names.

If you still have any questions, just ask ;)

You also can wrap it up to get more informations like this:

```
=IF((COUNTIFS(A$1:A1,B2,B$1:B1,A2)+COUNTIFS(A$1:A1,A2,B$1:B1,B2)),"",COUNTIFS(A:A,B2,B:B,A2)+COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,B2))
```

For C2 and copy down. C1 gets:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,B2,B:B,A2)+COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,B2)
```

This will show you only at the first occurrence how many times it is within the whole range.

*All done by phone, may contain errors*

Answer (score 0):

Use `=((A1*B1)/(A1+B1))*((A1*B1)+(A1+B1))` to create unique identifiers. Then use Remove Duplicates in the Data Tools Pane of the Data Tab to remove all rows containing duplicates. Or, alternatively, use something like `=IF(IFNA(MATCH(A2,A$1:A1,0),TRUE())=TRUE,"First Share","")` dragged and dropped from row 2 to identify First Shares.